# Is there a maximum size for 'hl.maxAnalyzedChars' in Solr highlighting?

Tags: search, solr, highlight

Is there a limit to the size I can increase the `hl.maxAnalyzedChars` parameter to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit to the size of hl.maxAnalyzedChars.

A value of -1 will give you unlimited characters, I've tested and confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a limit.  Have you tried hl.maxAnalyzedChars = -1?  That seems to be the solr default for unlimited characters, if that is what you are looking for.  Based on this bug report (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-610) it looks like it has been in since solr 1.3 or thereabouts.